# Indentation Style (Code style) Magento 2

Tags: magento2, best-practice, code, documentation

Hey, I wanna check if there is some documentation about the code style for magento, specially regarding the best practices Indentation style for magento.

I will give 2 examples, and I wanna also know the opion of the community about it.

1. Using PSR1/PS2 from phpstorm code style. (I believe it it's similar to the Magento 2)

```
$variable1 = "test";
$variableVariable2 = "test";
$variableVariable3 = "test";
$variableVariableVariable4 = "test";
```

2. Some custom code style that I found. (I don't think it's common see it on Magento 2 projects)

```
$variable1                 = "test";
$variableVariable2         = "test";
$variableVariable3         = "test";
$variableVariableVariable4 = "test";
```

I looked the documentation and I didn't find anything related to it. But based on what I saw in the project, it was buit using the Option 1. I just wanna make sure that is the option 1 the correct one, or if there is some sense about it, some documentation or article, anything is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configuring for Magento Coding Standard**
Verify it is installed with vendor/bin/phpcs -i . You should see Magento2 in the output. Go to **PHPStorm preferences > Editor > Inspections, and in the adjacent window go to PHP > Quality Tools > PHP_CodeSniffer validation. Under the Coding Standard dropdown, select Magento2** 
Refer to this link:- https://mirasvit.com/blog/guide-for-setting-up-phpstorm-for-magento-2-developments.html

Comment: Thank you. It was very usefull. 

Just a quick note. It was not showing Magento2 as option before. I had to go to "Preferences > PHP > Quality Tools > PHP_CodeSniffer > (Than I had to create clickin in the + icon a new interpreter and I chosen phpfpm from docker, there I inserted PHP_CodeSniffer path: /var/www/html/vendor/bin/phpcs, because I am using markshust/docker-magento).

Answer (score 0):

There PHP code sniffer tool available which contain the sets of Magento rules. You can install it within Magento project:
https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard.

All suggestions are fixable using the CLI command.